# OpenERP. How to make multiple invoices on a sale order when it contains products from different companies?

Tags: python, odoo, invoice, erp

How to make multiple invoices on a sale order when it contains products from different companies? My configuration is: - Main Company has: sub company 1, sub company 2. These companies has many products. I wish make multiple invoices when I create a sale order if it contains products from different companies. For example: Sale order contains: - Product A: sub company 1. - Product B: sub company 2. This sale order should make two invoices but in one sale order. It is like group by order lines by company from product.
I use OpenERP 7 2014-March.

Answer (score 0):

you have to override a create method in Invoice Model